# Safety about zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have encountered a problem about zookeeper's safety. I have a zookeeper&kafka, and I use sasl to protect zookeeper. Whereas I found that 'zkcli' has a bug, that is even if I don't provide sasl's username and password, I can still access the zoopkeeper's znode. The problem explains below:

http://zookeeper-user.578899.n2.nabble.com/SASL-for-Client-connections-td7583502.html#a7583510

I wonder is there a way can make the zookeeper safer. I know that setacl can protect the zookeeper's znode, but I found that it will cause some kafka error if using setcal in zookeeper. Is there a better way? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it helps you, but maybe :)

Here's what I've done for part of your problem (no SASL): a white list of valid client IPs.

- add to zkServer.sh
  `-Dzookeeper.authProvider.1=MyCustomIPAuthenticationProvider`
- create all the znodes using `withACL(ZooDefs.Ids.CREATOR_ALL_ACL)` (assuming Curator)

and

```
public class MyCustomIPAuthenticationProvider extends org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.IPAuthenticationProvider {

    private static Set<String> validHosts = new HashSet<>(); // todo populate

    @Override
    public KeeperException.Code handleAuthentication(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn cnxn, byte[] authData) {
        String id = cnxn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress();
        if (! matches(id, null) || ! matches(new String(authData), null)) {
            return org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.Code.AUTHFAILED;
        }
        return super.handleAuthentication(cnxn, authData);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(String id, String aclExpr) {
        return validHosts.contains(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

note it is not 100% secure (the client can fake his IP).
(And the use case was without Kafka!)

Comment: I found a solution, when using zookeeper with kafka, the server.properties of kafka should open setacl option like this: zookeeper.set.acl=true